# Good tutorial on static members, methods, context and keyword, and scope resolution

Tags: php, static

I'm having difficulty understanding how 'static' stuff works in PHP.  Can someone point me to a good tutorial on this?  One that comprehensively covers the topic?

I understand the use of static variables within a function, and also static members in a class.  Beyond that, however, it gets a bit hazy.

For example: I see that static methods can be called without instantiating a class.  Not sure why this is important though, since you can call a non-static method in exactly the same way, provided it does not reference $this

Late static binding is another area of confusion, along with when and where I can use the scope resolution operator.  (It seems I can use it to call parent methods irrespective of whether they are static or not...)

Am I the only one struggling with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can call a non-static method without an instance, this will trigger an `E_STRICT` warning. The whole point of static methods is for accessing static variables on the class, but many people use it as a way to logically group utility functions rather than define a bunch of global functions.

When you call a static method using the class's name, e.g. `Class::foo()`, there is no instance and thus no polymorphism. The `foo` defined by `Class` is called directly. If it doesn't define such a method, its superclasses are searched until one is found that does.

```
class Parent {
    static function foo() {
        echo "Parent::foo";
    }
    static function bar() {
        echo "Parent::bar";
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static function foo() {
        echo "Child::foo";
    }
}

Parent::foo();   // Parent::foo
Parent::bar();   // Parent::bar

Child::foo();    // Child::foo
Child::bar();    // Parent::bar
```

When you call a static method using the `self` keyword from a class method, e.g. `self::foo()`, it works just as if you were to replace `self` with the name of the class holding the calling code.

```
class Parent {
    static function foo() {
        echo "Parent::foo";
    }
    static function callFoo() {
        self::foo();    // equivalent to Parent::foo()
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static function foo() {
        echo "Child::foo";
    }
}

Parent::callFoo();   // Parent::foo
Child::callFoo();    // Parent::foo
```

When you call a static method using the `static` keyword from a class method, e.g. `static::foo()`, you are invoking [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). Instead of starting the search for `foo` in the current class, it starts from the current class context, the class that was initially statically-referenced.

```
class Parent {
    static function foo() {
        echo "Parent::foo";
    }
    static function callFoo() {
        static::foo();         // late static binding
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static function foo() {
        echo "Child::foo";
    }
    static function callParentCallFoo() {
        Parent::callFoo();    // resets static context to Parent
    }
}

Parent::callFoo();             // Parent::foo
Child::callFoo();              // Child::foo
Child::callParentCallFoo();    // Parent::foo
```

Late static binding works similarly with static class properties, but the property must be defined in the child class itself. Assigning a new property to a class (e.g. `Child::$foo = 'foo'`) will not make it available for LSB from the parent.

Comment: Phew, Thanks!  I'm going to need to go through this carefully to get my head around it...

Comment: The best way to learn it and make it stick is by playing with simple examples in PHP.

Comment: Thanks.  Think I've got it now.